# DiscountSavings() method using 0 instead of assigned value

Tags: java

When I call the DiscountSavings method inside the TwoHundred method it is taking 
the Discount value to be 0 instead of the 0.75 I have assigned.
I want the program to take user input for coffee bags to be purchased, calculate the gross cost, calculate the amount saved/discount, and then calculate the net cost after discounts.
If the user buys between 200 and 300 bags I want a 25% discount to be applied to the cost, yet my output is as follows:
Enter amount you would like to buy: 250
Number of bags ordered : 250 Gross Cost: 1375.0
Discount : 1.0 Total Saved 1375.0
 Total cost is 0.0
I plan on extending the code to apply different discounts at different bag quantities so I would like a method I can call instead of inputting each time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhyIsntThisWorking {
    public static double AmountSaved;
    public static double GrossCost;
    public static double Discount;
    public static double Cost;
    public static double Savings;

    public static double Gross(int Quantity) {
        GrossCost = Quantity*5.50;
        System.out.println("Number of bags ordered : " + Quantity + " Gross Cost: " + GrossCost);
        return GrossCost;
    }

    public static double DiscountSavings(double Discount, double GrossCost) {
        AmountSaved = 1 - Discount;
        Savings = GrossCost*AmountSaved;
        System.out.println("Discount : "+ AmountSaved + " Total Saved " + Savings);
        return AmountSaved;         
    }

    public static double TwoHundred(int Quantity){
        if( Quantity <199 &&  Quantity <300)
        Discount = 0.75;
        DiscountSavings( Discount, GrossCost);      
        Cost = (5.50* Quantity)*Discount;
        System.out.print(" Total cost is " + Cost);
        return Discount;
    }

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter amount you would like to buy: ");
        int Quantity = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        Gross(Quantity);
        TwoHundred(Quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if( Quantity <199 &&  Quantity <300)`? Also indent properly and use braces with if/while/etc.

Comment: if( Quantity > 199 &&  Quantity <300)// change it. syntax error

Comment: @SSP There is no syntax error on that line?

Comment: @DrRoach changing Quantity <199 from Quantity > 199. its error in code. not single line if

Comment: @SSP Ah I see, the syntax error bit confused me

Comment: yeah. pretty miner mistake

Comment: @SSP seeing as it's valid syntax, it's a logical error , not a syntax error

Comment: thanks solved, the quantity < 199 should have been Quantity > 199.